# Splitting cell data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split

I have imported data from a CSV that has been put into a single cell

e.g.

```
153863$10.26%153.9k
```

I want this data separated into 3 cells with no human input other than the import of the data itself.

```
153863 | 10.26% | 153.9k
```

The $ is not needed but it's inconsequently if it hangs around.

EDIT: I should of stated I dont need the original cell changed but read and data split into cells elsewhere on the sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"^(\d+)\$(\d+\.\d+%)(\d+.\d+k)$"))
```